# How can I access a folder outside of the terraform root module?

Tags: lambda, module, terraform, zip

I am trying to deploy a lambda using terraform. One of the steps in the lambda module zips up the source folder for the lambda. However, when I run the following code I am met with this error:
`Error: error archiving directory: could not archive missing directory: ./../hello-world`

This is my current folder structure

[image: Folder Structure]

Here is my lambda terraform for the zip step:

```
data "archive_file" "lambda_hello_world" {
  type = "zip"

  source_dir  = "${path.root}/../hello-world"
  output_path = "${path.root}/../hello-world.zip"
}
```

Pipeline code:

```
name: Deploy Infrastructure

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: './terraform/'
    steps:

    - name: Checkout Repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
      with:
        # terraform_version: 0.13.0
        cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TF_API_TOKEN }}

    - name: Terraform Format
      id: fmt
      run: terraform fmt -check

    - name: Terraform Init
      id: init
      run: terraform init

    - name: Terraform Validate
      id: validate
      run: terraform validate -no-color

    - name: Terraform Plan
      id: plan
      run: terraform plan -no-color
      continue-on-error: true

    - name: Terraform Plan Status
      if: steps.plan.outcome == 'failure'
      run: exit 1
    
    - name: Terraform Apply
      run: terraform apply -auto-approve
```

Comment: The error says that you are using `modules/lambdas/../../hello-world`, but your code has different paths. How come?

Comment: My bad, just updated with the correct error from my pipeline.

Comment: The code is correct. The issue must be with your pipeline that is not shown nor explained. Maybe it changes some folders.

Comment: I have added my pipeline code

Comment: Do you know absolute path of your `hello-world` folder? You can try with that, just to check if the folder is found.

Comment: The reference looks correct. Any chance the hello-world directory isn't in the repository on this branch?

Comment: The hello-world directory is definitely in the repo. I wonder if it's because of the change working directory line in the pipeline

Comment: I must admit I can't explain why this isn't working from the information given -- seems like something quirky about GitHub Actions -- but since you have a pipeline anyway I'd typically recommend making the build step of packaging up your source code be done outside of Terraform anyway, since Terraform is not a build tool. `archive_file` is no different than running the `zip` command from a prior step in the workflow, and then you could pass the zip file path as an input variable to Terraform.

Comment: This will be my apprach, uploading the artifacts in one pipeline and downloading in another.

Comment: I am in a similar situation.
I have a "terraform" folder and next to it I have another folder which includes  a Dockerfile. 
Terraform will build the docker image based on the Dockerfile if I put it in the terraform root folder or any of it's subfolders.
BUT if I use the folder next to the terraform root folder I get "Unexpected EOF".
Maybe there is some logic for it, would be nice if someone could confirm this is by design?